# rsyslog.conf only partly honored

Tags: samba, logging, syslog

I followed [this description on how to enable audit for Samba](http://moiristo.wordpress.com/) (entry of Aug 10, 2009) and wanted to get all additionally enabled logging in a special log file (`/var/log/samba/log.audit`).  The mentioned line `local7.* /var/log/samba/log.audit` I placed at the end of my existing `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file.  It seemed a bit out of place there, but after restarting everything, the mentioned file was created, presumably by the syslog daemon, so I assumed this was working.

But it stayed at a size of 0 bytes.  After creation of the file, nothing was logged there.

It took me some time but then I found that all logging was done into the default syslog file (`/var/log/syslog`).

I guess the config line in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` is correct, but somehow the way it was supposed to be addressed in the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` is not working.

I repeat in short what the blog above suggested to do:

Add the lines

```
vfs objects = full_audit

full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
full_audit:success = mkdir rename unlink rmdir pwrite
full_audit:failure = none
full_audit:facility = local7
full_audit:priority = NOTICE
```

to the existing `smb.conf` and add the line

```
local7.*                        /var/log/samba/log.audit
```

to the `syslog.conf` (I took my existing `/etc/rsyslog.conf` for this).

Can anybody tell me how to fix this so that the logging is done into the intended file `/var/log/samba/log.audit`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I changed the output log file location to `/var/log` instead of `/var/log/samba`. I'm not sure why, but it seems `rsyslog` on my system won't write a facility to a file outside `/var/log`.

Hope that helps, and if anyone knows how to configure `ryslog` to allow other locations it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

The `/var/log/samba/log.audit` file must have `syslog` as the owning user, and `adm` as the owning group.

If it is not like this, run:

```
sudo chown /var/log/samba/log.audit syslog:adm
```

Comment: I will check that and come back!  (Let's hope I don't forget it after so much time passed …)

Comment: Sorry, the ownership and permissions already are as they should be (syslog.adm with 640), so that is no solution.